If you have large group sizes (>1000), are there any differences between fixed + random effects models?
If you have large group sizes (>1000), are there any practical differences between using a fixed effect model and a random effects model?
A concrete example might be where your individuals are all the children in a state and your groups are counties.

Yes, they model different things, the size does not matter.

Why would sample size matter?

@PeterFlom It seemed to me that the pooling property of the random effect would do less and less effective as the sample size increased. To give an example, suppose you are trying to determine a teacher's effect on class performance, controlling for student variables. If the class sizes are 3, then it's likely that the better performing classes do so due to chance. If the class sizes are 300, then substantive discrepancies between class performances seem to be likely to be due to the teacher.

The decision to use a fixed or random effects models usually has little to do with sample size (either at the group or observation level) one way or the other. These two kinds of models answer different kinds of questions and/or have different strengths and weaknesses. For example...
If you want to analyze the effect of group level variables you can't use a fixed effects model because any group level variables will drop out of the model (they are perfectly colinear with the group level dummies).
If you want to account for group level bias but don't have a good selection of group level control variables, then you probably want to use a fixed effects model, although you could run a Hausman test to check if the group level bias is severe enough to matter.
If you want to estimate the proportion of variance at the group vs observation level, or use empirical bayes estimation to pool information across clusters, then you have to use a random effects model since those analyses require random effects to work.
Those are just a few of the factors that you might consider when deciding between a fixed and random effects model, none of which have much to do with sample size, except indirectly.

And also: fixed effects are not assumed to be normally distributed, whereas random effects should be.

Given large groups, to analyze the effect of group level variables, why can't you run a fixed effects model and then run a second analysis on the group-level numbers that come out of that? E.g. I could a) run a fixed effects model to find the effect level for each county (using per-child covariates) and then b) take those per-county numbers and run a second regression on those to see how they are linked to county-level characteristics?  That two-stage method seems to me better as it does not require distributional assumptions...
